# 3G Connection Not Working on Samsung Galaxy S2

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-s-2, 3g

I have a Galaxy S2 that for some reason does not work when it's connected to a 3G network(or at least I think it's connected, there's a '3G' symbol next to my signal meter). When I say it doesn't work, I mean that I don't have any data connection what-so-ever. No internet, nothing.

When my phone is connected with the 'H+' symbol next to the signal meter then everything works perfectly. But the problem is that my phone is constantly trying to use 3G, which of course is useless.

**My phone details are:**

Model Number:       GT-I9100

Android Version:    2.3.3

Baseband version:   I9100XXKE7

Kernal Version:     2.6.35.7-I9100XWKF3-CL276555root@DELL101 #2

Build number:       GINGERBREAD.XWKF3

If anyone has an idea why this would happen, please give me a shout. It's so frustrating having no data connection for the most of my day. Also if there's a way to just stop the phone completely from trying to connect/use a 3G connection. That would be great.

PS - I'm in South Africa and my carrier is 'Cell C'.

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could try going into Settings - Wireless and Networks - Mobile Networks - Tick use only 2G networks.

That will disable 3G connectivity.

If you wish to disable mobile data, then un-tick the mobile data option.

Answer (score 1):

Airplane mode would kill the 3G connection.... but it would also kill the Wifi connection.

[APNDroid](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.codecarpet.apndroid.pro) can kill just the 3G connection.

As for the actual 3G problem... have you talked to your carrier?  Does your phone have to know some sort of [preferred roaming list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preferred_Roaming_List) that it is missing?